# How to input text from docx to Android Studio in its original form?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am making a simple android app(in Android Studio) and one of the parts of the app requires showing text that I wrote in docx. When I paste my text in a textView, all my new lines are gone, I'm left with text as If I was typing it in a notepad.

How can I import text and maintain it's original form? (It wouldn't be a problem if it was one smaller text, but there's a lot of it and manualy correcting it would take a lot of time,and it's not really efficient)

[image: How it looks in docx(example text)]

[image: How it looks in android studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Word seems like the wrong approach to me, but the textview supports html, which should be suffient for your example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("
Lorem ..<br\> 
Lorem ...<br\> 
<ol>
   <li>Lorem ...</li>
   <li>LOREM ...</li>
</ol>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Comment: I just have all my text in word, that is why i mentioned it. I will try your solustion to change my word text to html text, and insert it like that,thanks!